# How to work with dynamic parameters of teams messaging Extension?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

with the new addition of developer portal, how do you configure a messaging Extension with action command having dynamic parameter.

[Developer portal popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfNC7.png)

Comment: You can add provide the height, width and the web url to load for task module. These fields are already mentioned in the screenshot you have shared.

Comment: @Aastitva Jain- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the variables under "Environment" section, using developer portal like below:

[image]

Afterwards, you can use that variable while adding the Messaging Extension commands like below:

[image]

Comment: @Aastitva Jain- Could you please confirm if your issue has resolved with above suggestion or still looking for any help?